# Maximal entropy function of multiple random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, entropy

Assume that we have a known multivariate distribution of $N$ variables denoted by $f(\vec{X})$.

Consider the random variable $Y = g(\vec{X})$ defined by a smooth function $g:\mathbb{R^{n}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
I wish to find the function $g$ which maximize the entropy of $Y$ given $f(\vec{X})$.

Solutions to the general problem under any non-trivial constraints are of interest to me.

I tried using variational calculus for this task but couldn't come up with something other than the fact that $Y$ should be uniformly distributed, yet I still can't seem to find the form of $g$ given $f(\vec{X})$. I'm looking for any reference for a solution under any constraint on $g$, even in special cases(such as multivariate gaussian, or iid random variables).

Comment: "which maximize the entropy of Y given $f(X)$" What does that mean. ? You mean some conditional entropy, or merely that $f$ is known?.

Comment: Do you think this maximum exists ? If $g$ is your solution then $ag$ gives lower entropy for all real $a$, but I don’t think this is the case. So you can make your entropy go to infinity. This is informal but I think if $X$ is a one dimensional Gaussian the argument works for instance. You may want additional constraint on $g$.

Comment: answering @leonbloy, merely that $f$ is known.

Comment: Answering @P.Quinton, you are absolutely right, I'll edit my question to clarify that I'm interested in any reference to the question and its answer under non-trivial constraints on $g$ or general settings.

Comment: "couldn't come up with something other than the fact that  $Y$ should be uniformly distributed". Why? Suppose $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$, then you could map it to a gaussian, or even to so heavy tailed distribution with infinite (differential) entropy. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155939/is-differential-entropy-always-less-than-infinity 
As stated, the problem makes little sense.